# Convert KM to Polyline overlay in Google Maps V3?

Tags: javascript, xml, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I have an KML file with a bunch of coordinates. I do not really need the rest of the data in there like color, name, etc. Is there an easy way to extract all the coordinates and plot them using the Polyline API? I can use C# is that helps, but sticking to client side would be nice. Thanks fo any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is to display the data, adding a `KmlLayer` is sufficient:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#KMLLayers

Otherwise, for more complicated manipulation, geoxml3 might be helpful.

http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/wiki/Usage

Answer (score 0):

Remember that KML files are simply xml feeds.

Client side:

- Use a service such as the [Google Feed API](https://developers.google.com/feed/) to get the data using only javascript.

Server side (C#):

- Use the [XmlDocument class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) to retrieve and work with the KML file. Since KML files contain XML Namespaces, you'll also likely need to use [XmlNamespaceManager class](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318545). The XmlDocument Load method can handle a URL.